# How to write insert function or query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables which are very extensive, but I will give only a small version:

employee_position :

| ID | position |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Programmer |
| 2 | Administrator |
| 3 | Analyst |

employee:

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam Smith |
| 2 | Sam Jones |
| 3 | Barbra Streisand |
| 4 | Dorothy Brown |

employee_functions:

| ID | employee_id | employee_position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |

Assuming what I need: if there is no employee in the employee_functions table [from the employee table] with an assigned position, then all positions in the employee_positions table should be assigned to him in this table.
I admit that I am not very fluent in SQL, so I would ask for help, can it be done with one query or can I do some function?

The final result for the given data (employee_functions):

| ID | employee_id | employee_position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 | 1 |
| 7 | 4 | 2 |
| 8 | 4 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert . . . select`, filtering out the employees who already have functions:

```
   insert into employee_functions (employee_id, position_id)
           select e.id, p.id
           from employee e cross join
                employee_positions ep
           where not exists (select 1
                             from employee_functions ef
                             where ef.employee_id = e.id
                            );
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select employee_id ,employee_position from employee_functions f
union all 
select e.id, p.id from employees e
cross join employee_position p
where e.id not in (select employee_id from employee_functions)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into employee_functions (employee_id, position_id)
      select e.id, p.id
       from employee e cross join
            employee_positions ep
       where not exists (select 1
                         from employee_functions ef
                         where ef.employee_id = e.id
                        );
```